# Connecting AWS cassandra using c#

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, cassandra

I am trying to Connect to AWS Cassandra using this code:

```
       var pathToCAFile = $"{Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()}/AmazonRootCA1.pem";
        X509Certificate2[] certs = new X509Certificate2[] { new X509Certificate2(pathToCAFile, "amazon") };
        X509Certificate2Collection certificateCollection = new X509Certificate2Collection(certs);
        var options = new Cassandra.SSLOptions(SslProtocols.Tls11, true, ValidateServerCertificate);
        options.SetCertificateCollection(certificateCollection);
        Cluster cluster = Cluster
                            .Builder()
                            .WithCredentials("username", "password")
                            .WithPort(9142)
                            .AddContactPoint("cassandra.us-east-1.amazonaws.com")
                           .WithSSL()
                            .WithLoadBalancingPolicy(new DefaultLoadBalancingPolicy("us-east-1"))
                            .Build();

        // Connect to the nodes using a keyspace
        var session = cluster.Connect("system_distributed");
```

```
        // Execute a query on a connection synchronously
        var rs = session.Execute("select * from system.peers");
```

Here is the error that I'm getting:

> "Cassandra.NoHostAvailableException: 'All hosts tried for query failed
>   (tried 3.83.169.143:9142: AuthenticationException 'The remote
>   certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.')'

This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:

> Cassandra.Connections.Control.ControlConnection.Connect(bool)
>     System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>     System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
>     System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
>     System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
>     Cassandra.Connections.Control.ControlConnection.InitAsync()
>     System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>     System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
>     System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
>     System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
>       ...
>       [Call Stack Truncated]

Answer (score 2):

I assume you're using the DataStax C# driver. If that is the case there's this documentation section on SSL/TLS which also has links to a couple of examples: https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/csharp-driver/3.15/features/tls/

If that snippet is accurate, you're not actually setting the `SSLOptions` on the `Builder.WithSSL()` method.

If that doesn't work and the code examples don't help you, please show us the `ValidateServerCertificate` method so we can see what might be going wrong on the certificate validation.

---

### Edit (from my comment below):

On [TLS/SSL documentation page](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/csharp-driver/3.15/features/tls/#enabling-server-authentication-with-a-custom-root-certificate) there is a section that is relevant here: *Enabling server authentication with a custom root certificate*.

As mentioned in the documentation, you either have to install that certificate in the machine where the application is running or you have to provide a custom certificate validator similar to [this one](https://github.com/datastax/csharp-driver/blob/master/examples/Ssl/SslServerAuthOnly/LoadingCertificateManuallyExample.cs).

The `SSLOptions.SetCertificateCollection()` method is used for client authentication so it is not useful for your situation where you want server authentication.

Comment: public static bool ValidateServerCertificate(
              object sender,
              X509Certificate certificate,
              X509Chain chain,
              SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
        {
            if (sslPolicyErrors == SslPolicyErrors.None)
                return true;

            Console.WriteLine("Certificate error: {0}", sslPolicyErrors);

            // Do not allow this client to communicate with unauthenticated servers.
            return false;
        }

This is ValidateServerCertificate Method

Comment: In console I get error as RemoteCertificateNameMisMatch

Comment: https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/csharp-driver/3.15/features/tls/  

I had also tried from here..then to I get the same error 

" Cassandra.NoHostAvailableException: 'All hosts tried for query failed (tried 3.83.169.143:9142: AuthenticationException 'The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.')'

Comment: On that page there is a section that is relevant here: "Enabling server authentication with a custom root certificate". As mentioned in the documentation, you either have to install that certificate in the machine where the application is running or you have to provide a custom certificate validator similar to this one: https://github.com/datastax/csharp-driver/blob/master/examples/Ssl/SslServerAuthOnly/LoadingCertificateManuallyExample.cs

Comment: The SetCertificateCollection() method is used for client authentication so it is not useful for your situation where you want server authentication.